# Is it possible to attach UNIX socket as STDIN to process in bash?

Tags: bash, sockets, unix

Is it possible to attach UNIX socket as STDIN to a command or process?

Something like:

```
/var/run/input.sock | command
```

Comment: I believe a UNIX socket is just a file, so you should be able to do `command < /var/run/input.sock`.

Comment: Hmm, does not look possible - command thinks, that `/var/run/input.sock` is a string. I use `nc`, by the way to open socket connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use socat:

```
socat -T 3 unix-connect:/var/run/input.sock stdout | command
```

**Installing socat:**

centos:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo epel install socat
```

**Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install socat
```

**More info:**

http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html

http://technostuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html

Comment: Is it possible to use netcat ('nc') in the same way?

Comment: Also, looks like that `socat` times out, but if I remove `-T 3`, `command` does not receive input.

Comment: @JustasBrazauskas you can't use `nc` in the same way, `nc` only works for network sockets. WRT `socat` probably your socket does not print anything, perhaps it waits for you send some command.

Comment: Hm, `nc` can connect to UNIX socket, so it should work.
Regarding `socat` - I write to socket manually, so command should execute, what I send it.

Comment: As far as I know `nc` is for TCP and UDP sockets only. I would need to know more about what you're trying to do in order to help. How are you wrtiting  to socket? if you're already writing what's the trouble to read it?

Comment: What I want to do is to launch a program (lets say node.js app), and have a socket, that can write to STDIN of node, and have separate socket, that gets all node\`s *OUT

Comment: openbsd nc (included with some Linux distros) can connect to UNIX sockets using -U , gnu nc can't, ncat (from nmap) can.